# Find a limit of the function sequence $f_n(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to find a limit of the function sequence $f_n(x)$ defined on $(0, \infty)$:

$f_n(x)=(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})^n \cdot e^{-\sqrt{n}\space x}$

Can you express the limit function of $f_n(x)$?
In other words, what is the form of $g(x)= \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$f_n=\left(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n \ e^{-\sqrt{n}\, x}$$
$$\log(f_n)=n \log\left(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\sqrt{n}x$$ Now, by Taylor for large $n$
$$\log(f_n)=n\left(\frac x{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{x^2}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)\right)-\sqrt{n}x= ???$$
$$f_n=e^{\log(f_n)}=e^{???}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} [1+(x/\sqrt{n})]^{n} \to 1 ^{\infty}$$
When $n$ is very large, then $f_n(x) \sim n (1+x/\sqrt{n}-1) \sim x \sqrt{n}.$
Finally, $$g(x)= \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) e^{-\sqrt{n}} x$= x\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} e^{-\sqrt{n}}=0$$

Comment: This does not seem to be correct